# Override color in Android style

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-holo-everywhere

I know that with the  [color generators](http://android-holo-colors.com/) I can generate styling for most UI elements. Also using the  [action bar color generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) I can create colors for most (if not all) action bar elements.

But for some reason alert dialogs still escape those nice tools. No matter what I tried I can't change for ICS (and up) AlertDialog title underline color from blue.

is there anyway I can just override the colors themselves without having to point to individual elements?

Something like this (this doesn't work), but on the same idea of it:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" type="color">#F00</item>
        <item name="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" type="color">#F00</item>
        <item name="@android:color/holo_blue_light" type="color">#F00</item>
```